# Uber API iOS OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, oauth, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I was trying to make a iOS which will use the Uber API to do things like get rides and what not. I am trying to implement the OAuth 2.0 on the iPhone without using any server side help.

Is that possible? Has anyone done this?

Here are some references:

Uber Authentication: https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/

Oauth 2.0: https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

Comment: It should be possible, OAuth 2.0 allows that. Maybe you could get some inspiration from UberKit: https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/UberKit. It does user signin using an integrated WebView. As for the redirect URI, you might need to create a specific redirect URI within your app, and use it as the designated redirect URI in your Uber app's configuration (e.g.: myuberapp://oauth).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible. I was able to configure OAuth2 for my app using Uber API. Here are step-by-step instructions:

1. In your app, redirect to https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize with your client_id and `response_type=code` in order to allow user to authorize your app.
2. Upon successful authorization, Uber will redirect to your `redirect_uri` (you can specify any redirect_uri, including localhost:xxxx for testing purposes, etc.) to provide you with an auth code that is single-use and valid for 10 min. Implement a callback to retrieve this auth code.
3. With the valid auth code from Step 2, make a POST request to exchange for an access token. As a simple check, I would recommend using curl to confirm access token validity. For ex:
   `curl -F 'client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' \
       -F 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
       -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
       -F 'redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI' \
       -F 'code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE' \
       https://login.uber.com/oauth/token`
4. Upon successful exchange, use the access token as the value for the 'Authorization' header for subsequent endpoint calls. For ex:
   `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823'`

Comment: can you provide swift code for this. Im implementing this in my app

Comment: for swift click here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895238/uber-invalid-oauth-2-0-credentials-provided-uber-authentication-in-ios-swift