# Uber Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided Uber Authentication In ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, uber-api

I'm implementing the [Uber's Request Endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/#request) in my iOS (Swift) App. The Request API/Endpoint requires the user authentication with the app, here is the [doc](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/#oauth-2-0).

For this I'm using this [Oauth2.0 library](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2)

What I did is

1. successfully integrated the Library in my project (xCode) with the help of given installation instructions.
2. In My AppDelegate

   ```
   let uber_OAuth_Settings = [
   "client_id": "XXXXXXX9vtKzobvXXXXXX",
   "client_secret": "EXXXXXXXXyFUNCa_Wez6AXXXXXXXnrXtxus",
   "authorize_uri": "https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize",
   "token_uri": "https://login.uber.com/oauth/token",
   "redirect_uris": ["jamesappv2://oauth/callback"],   // don't forget to register this scheme
   ] as OAuth2JSON
   ```

   var oauth:OAuth2CodeGrant!
3. in my method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of Appdelegate

   ```
    oauth = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: uber_OAuth_Settings)
   oauth.viewTitle = "Uber Login Service"      // optional
   oauth.verbose = true // For Logs
   ```
4. Don't forget to register url scheme i.e (`"redirect_uris": ["jamesappv2://oauth/callback"]`)

goto your app's Target -> info Tab -> Url Types -> Click (+), image attached

[image]

5. In AppDelegate add method given Below and Handle the Callback Url

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication,
   openURL url: NSURL,
   sourceApplication: String?,
   annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
       // you should probably first check if this is your URL being opened

      var splitUrl = url.absoluteString!.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

       if splitUrl[0] == ("jamesappv2") {

           oauth.handleRedirectURL(url)
       }

       return true
   }
   ```
6. Now in my viewController I did like this on myBtnClick

   ```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

   let url = appDelegate.oauth.authorizeURL()
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)        
   appDelegate.oauth.onAuthorize = { parameters in
       println("Did authorize with parameters: \(parameters)")

       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.PersonalDriverUber_VC, animated: true)
   //On Authorization Goto another ViewController using pushViewController of navigationcontroller Method

   }
   appDelegate.oauth.onFailure = { error in        // `error` is nil on cancel
       if nil != error {
           println("Authorization went wrong: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
       }
   }
   ```

Here is my debug log, I'm getting the valid response:

```
    OAuth2: Handling redirect URL jamesappv2://oauth/callback?state=4B0EB812&code=0sXXXXXXTX7yEbS1XXXXXHuw
OAuth2: Successfully validated redirect URL
OAuth2: Authorizing against https://login.uber.com/oauth/token?state=38158941&grant_type=authorization_code&code=0sXXXXXXXX1jxTrdFQT9Huw&client_secret=EIXXXXXXXNCa_Wez6XXXXXw0BlnrXtxus&client_id=fXXXXXXXy2LOUo9vtKXXXXXQ1nUDO&redirect_uri=jamesappv2%3A%2F%2Foauth%2Fcallback
OAuth2: Exchanging code 0swNXXXXX7yXXXXXXdFQT9Huw with redirect jamesappv2://oauth/callback for token at Optional("https://login.uber.com/oauth/token")
OAuth2: Did receive access token: Dfq3XXXXXXuWgpaqFXXXXXXXgXW, refresh token: EmStT7FEXHRMlS8odPzs1nsha0ObjK
Did authorize with parameters: [token_type: Bearer, expires_in: 2592000, access_token: XXXXXXOZuWgXXXXXXXXuJYOmgXW, refresh_token: EXXXXXHRMlS8oXXXXXXXa0ObjK, scope: profile, last_authenticated: 1430121470]
```

*Notice* I'm getting the valid access_token

**Here I'm stuck**

As per [DOCs](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/#oauth-2-0) says in STEP4 *USE BEARER TOKEN

Pass the access_token returned in the response in the Authorization header with the type Bearer to make requests on behalf of a user.*

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' 'https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823'
```

I am not getting the point. How should I pass the access_token in Header with type Bearer? I have done like below

```
func callRequestAPI(url:String){

    let request = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: NSURL(string:url)!)



    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"


    let postString = "product_id="+selectedUberProductId+"&start_latitude="+start_lat+"&start_longitude="+start_lng+"&end_latitude="+end_lat+"&end_longitude="+end_lng

    println(postString)


    let tempData: NSData = appDelegate.oauth.accessToken.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let base64LoginString = tempData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")




   request.setValue("Bearer \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in


        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

but I'm getting following response

```
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1a284b50> { URL: https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests } { status code: 401, headers {
"Content-Length" = 75;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Mon, 27 Apr 2015 10:22:01 GMT";
Server = nginx;
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
"x-uber-app" = "uberex-sandbox";
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
responseString = Optional({"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"})
```

Comment: Have a look at the request with charles, maybe you spott the error.

Comment: sorry yene I am not getting you.

Comment: @QadirHussain Charles is a network monitoring tool. It makes it easy to see what's being sent back and forward from your simulator and the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have done it :)

I changed the method like below and it Worked

```
func callRequestAPI(url:String){

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

    let params:[String: AnyObject] = [
        "product_id" : selectedUberProductId,
        "start_latitude" : start_lat,
        "start_longitude" : start_lng,
        "end_latitude" : end_lat,
        "end_longitude" : end_lng]



    let request = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: NSURL(string:url)!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.allZeros, error: &err)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 202 {
                println("response was not 202: \(response)")

                return
            }
        }
        if (error != nil) {
            println("error submitting request: \(error)")
            return
        }

        // handle the data of the successful response here
        var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! NSDictionary


        println(result)

        if let request_id: String = result["request_id"] as? String{

            println(request_id)
        }

        if let driver: String = result["driver"] as? String{

            println(driver)
        }

        if let eta: Int = result["eta"] as? Int{

            println(eta)
        }

        if let location: String = result["location"] as? String{

            println(location)
        }


        if let status: String = result["status"] as? String{

            println(status)
        }


        if let surge_multiplier: Int = result["surge_multiplier"] as? Int{

            println(surge_multiplier)
        }

        if let vehicle: String = result["vehicle"] as? String{

            println(vehicle)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

here is the Response I Got, Parsing is also given in my above method

```
{
  driver = "<null>";
  eta = 15;
  location = "<null>";
  "request_id" = "ea39493d-b718-429f-8710-00a34dcdaa93";
  status = processing;
  "surge_multiplier" = 1;
  vehicle = "<null>";
}
```

Enjoy

Comment: what changes did you make in this method ?

Comment: @Jagdeep please see the callRequestAPI() in my question and compare with same in my answer. you see the differances :)

Comment: i can identify two difference quickly which are param post and header content. is that correct ?

Comment: How did you authorize the user's uber account with your app? I am trying to find examples of how this is done and can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift 2. I used the same setup and library for oauth that Qadir describes in his question. I updated his request to work in Swift 2. Hope this helps others.

uberRequest:

```
    let params:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "product_id" : uberProduct,
        "start_latitude" : userLat,
        "start_longitude" : userLng,
        "end_latitude" : barLat,
        "end_longitude" : barLng]

    let urlPath = "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests"
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else { print("Error creating endpoint");return }

    let request = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: NSURL(string:urlPath)!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    print("Prepare to make request -> \(request)")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error -> \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            print("Result -> \(result)")

        } catch {
            print("Error -> \(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

It returns:

```
Result -> Optional(["driver": <null>, "request_id": 5834384c-7283-4fe6-88a7-e74150c6ab30, "surge_multiplier": 1, "location": <null>, "vehicle": <null>, "status": processing, "eta": <null>])
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the token just follow step 5 of the instructions in the `OAuth2` library, like you did before you started to try to sign it yourself a second time. The request has already been signed and has the Bearer token set up, there is nothing left to do for you:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823")
let req = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: url)

// customize your request, if needed. E.g. for POST:
req.HTTPMethod = "POST"

// send the request
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(req) { data, response, error in
    if nil != error {
        // something went wrong
    }
    else {
        // check the response and the data
        // you have just received data with an OAuth2-signed request!
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: yes but I have to send a post request. When I send the POST request for driver request Endpoint, code is given above it returns me {"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"} :(

Comment: I have the same problem. How do I send the OAuth 2.0 credentials? I have received the access token but how to use it?

Comment: If you do `appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: url)`, the credentials are already included in the request. I've updated the sample to show you where you can customize your request.