# Uber Authentication failed "HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"error": "invalid_client"}"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, uber-api

i am using [this](https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift) library for Uber Authetication

https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/

I have done like this

```
func doOAuthUber(){

let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "fXfXXXXXXXUo9vtKzobXXXXXUDO",
    consumerSecret: "e5XXXXXXXq2w63qz9szEx7uXXXXXXo03W",
    authorizeUrl:   "https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize",
    accessTokenUrl: "https://login.uber.com/oauth/token",
    responseType:   "code"
)

var originalString = "jamesappv2://oauth/callback"
var encodedCallBackUrl = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

println("encodedCallBackUrl: \(encodedCallBackUrl)")


let state: String = ""
oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: encodedCallBackUrl!)!, scope: "request%20history", state: state, success: {
    credential, response in

    println(credential.oauth_token)
    self.personalDriverLoader.stopAnimating()



    }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in

        self.personalDriverLoader.stopAnimating()
        println(error.localizedDescription)
})

}
```

but getting this response
HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"error": "invalid_client"}

I have triple checked that my client_id (consumerKey) and secret (consumerSecret) are correct.
What I have done wrong here

**Update:1**

this is wired I changed responseType: "code" to responseType: "token" and it worked Got My access token. but I am getting an other issue now

now when ever I try to call the [request endpoint api](https://developer.uber.com/v1/tutorials/#request)

using below code

```
@IBAction func btnRequestUberdidClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.callRequestAPI("https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests")

}

func callRequestAPI(url:String){

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

    let params:[String: AnyObject] = [
                "product_id" : selectedUberProductId,
                "start_latitude" : start_lat,
                "start_longitude" : start_lng,
                "end_latitude" : end_lat,
                "end_longitude" : end_lng]



    appDelegate.oauthswift.client.post(url, parameters: params,
    success: { data, response in

    let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)


         println("Success")

                    println(data)

                    println(response)


        }, failure: {(error:NSError!) -> Void in

                         println("Error")

                    println(error)
    })


}
```

I am getting this response

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"}" UserInfo=0x1c563220 {NSLocalizedDescription=HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.","code":"unauthorized"}, Response-Headers=<CFBasicHash 0x1c578c40 [0x35305710]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    1 : x-xss-protection = <CFString 0x1ae2fc60 [0x35305710]>{contents = "1; mode=block"}
    4 : Server = <CFString 0x1acc24c0 [0x35305710]>{contents = "nginx"}
    5 : Content-Type = <CFString 0x1c4d0020 [0x35305710]>{contents = "application/json"}
    6 : Content-Length = <CFString 0x1c4b70b0 [0x35305710]>{contents = "75"}
    8 : Date = <CFString 0x1c4ed4b0 [0x35305710]>{contents = "Wed, 06 May 2015 12:46:51 GMT"}
    10 : Strict-Transport-Security = <CFString 0x1c225cb0 [0x35305710]>{contents = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"}
    11 : x-uber-app = <CFString 0x1c49a6b0 [0x35305710]>{contents = "uberex-sandbox"}
}
}
```

Comment: Uber API needs OAuth2 but you're using OAuth1's format of your lib. Check https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift#examples . And look in the [Uber API doc](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/), the auth is done in *three* steps, not one. :)

Comment: @EricD. thanks for response. how to use Oauth2 using this library. let me know what is wrong with this. you can see i have used OAuth2Swift

Comment: You're using the right `OAuth2Swift` object, *but* in it you're using the wrong declaration format. Look at the *last* example on the OAuthSwift page, there shouldn't be any `accessTokenUrl` in it. The, once you've got this response, follow the *redirect*, then, eventually, get the token. :)

Comment: this is wired I changed responseType:   "code" to responseType:   "token" and it worked (o0) . Got My access token. but I am getting an other issue now

Comment: I don't have an Uber account anymore, so I can't test or help any further with your example. Anyway, while searching for informations, I found your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29918588/2227743) where you seemed to have found a way to achieve this!!! I'm a bit puzzled now. :p

Comment: This is wrong, an access token url is most certainly required. It will crash if it's not included because it tries to use that to get a token later in OAuthSwiftHTTPRequest.

Comment: I'm also having this same problem. It's inexplicable at this point. I thought I had fixed it one time when I was missing a privacy policy and hadn't selected the scope correctly on their page, but now the problem is back and makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the library where possible and be able to print the auth code returned from Uber. I was facing a similar problem with Uber authentication using objective C and then I realised from my logs that Uber was appending `#_` to the authorization code. So when this code was used to fetch the access token, it would fail with `(401) unauthorised error` simply  saying the auth code is invalid, and indeed it was.

See attached image below.

[image]

So eventually I had to removed the `#_` from the auth code before using it to get the access token.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params1 = @{@"client_secret":UBER_CLIENT_SECRET,
                          @"client_id":UBER_CLIENT_ID,
                          @"grant_type":@"authorization_code",
                          @"redirect_uri":UBER_REDIRECT_URL,
                          @"code":[app.uberAuthCodeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#_" withString:@""]};
                    //******* THE FIX IS HERE ON THIS LINE ^^^

[manager POST:@"https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token" parameters:params1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    //
    app.uberBearerAccess_token = [responseObject valueForKey:@"access_token"];
    app.uberBearerRefresh_token = [responseObject valueForKey:@"refresh_token"];
    NSLog(@"Bearer AccessToken = %@ ",app.uberBearerAccess_token);
    // Save access token to user defaults for later use.
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *seconds = [responseObject objectForKey:@"expires_in"];
    NSDate *expiryDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:seconds.intValue];
    [defaults setObject:expiryDate forKey:KEY_UBER_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DATE];
    [defaults setObject:app.uberBearerAccess_token forKey: KEY_UBER_TOKEN];
    [defaults setObject:app.uberBearerRefresh_token forKey: KEY_UBER_REFRESH_TOKEN];
     [defaults setObject:app.uberAuthCodeStr forKey: KEY_UBER_AUTH_CODE];
    [defaults synchronize];
    loginView.hidden = YES;
    [self goUberChat];
    //
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@':%@", error,params1);
    [ProgressHUD dismiss];
}];
```

Hope this helps you or anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score -3):

Try this for call Uber Api

```
 NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.uber.com/v1/products"];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:string];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager=[[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"server_token":@"Your token",@"latitude":@"latitude",@"longitude":@"longitude",
    [manager GET: parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task,id responseObject){
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation , NSError *error)
}];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.