# implicit grant authentication with Uber Ride on android

Tags: android, uber-api

I want to use the implicit grant authentication in my android app. Currently I am having trouble in understanding what redirectUri I should supply. Should it be a deeplink to my app? Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

The `redirectUri` can be found on your UBER developer dashboard. Please see [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk#sdk-configuration) fore more details.

To redirect the user back to your own app, define your own URI scheme in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside the Activity that handles the response from UBER:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="your.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, in UBER's developer dashboard, you can set the following Redirect URL:

```
 your.special.scheme://callback
```

Once a user has authorized your app via the browser, UBER will send an authorization code back to your app using the above URI scheme. The authorization code will be supplied to your app via a "code" parameter, which you'll then use to create a credential-object:

```
Credential credential = credentials.authenticate(authorizationCode, userId);
```

See [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/java) and [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-java-sdk#create-a-session-using-the-oauth-2-flow) for details. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31203544/7874326) is an answer dealing with this issue for iOS.

Comment: I know that it is in there. But i just put http//:localhost there for cimplicity, which is obviously not correct. So the question is what should be the link.